# Reserving Ports on Windows Vista?

Tags: networking, windows-vista, port

Is there a way to reserve a range of ports on windows vista?

On windows XP and 2003 there was a registry key for that (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812873), does anyone know of a method to do so on Vista (or 2008)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to change the ephemeral port ranges?

Comment: fair enough, is there a way to check out what's the ephemeral port range, if it's not the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dynamic port range on Vista / 2008 starts at 49152 upto 65535.
You can define the Dynamic port range, not sure if you can *reserve* individual ports or ranges.

See the article below for more info.

[Dynamic Port Range in Windows Server 2008](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsServer2008/AdminTips/Network/DynamicPortRangeinWindowsServer2008.html)